# How to use np.vectorize?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have this function to vectorize:

```
if x >= y, then x*y
else x/y
```

My code is:

```
def vector_function(x, y):

    if y >= x:
      return x*y
    else:
      return x/y
  
    vfunc = np.vectorize(vector_function)
    return vfunc
    
  raise NotImplementedError
```

But I am getting the error:

```
'>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please check the indentation of your code, because for now it seem no code can be executed after the `if/else`

Comment: Isn't the answer to `How to use np.vectorize?` usually "Don't. It just pretends to be a vectorized function but is just a loop with a different name"?

Comment: From [numpy.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html): *The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.*

Comment: If you are aware of this, why don't you include this information in your answer? SO is a database to provide the best possible answer, not the code a customer requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `vectorize`-call *inside* the function.

```py
import numpy as np

# first define the function
def vector_function(x, y):
    if y >= x:
        return x * y
    else:
        return x / y

# vectorize it
vfunc = np.vectorize(vector_function)

# validation
print(vfunc([1, 2, 3, 4], 2.5)) # [2.5 5.  1.2 1.6]
```

Note, however, from [numpy.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html): *The `vectorize` function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.*

Answer (score 2):

A pure "vectorized" version is:

```
def foo(x,y):
    return np.where(y>=x, x*y, x/y)

In [317]: foo(np.array([1,2,3,4]), 2.5)
Out[317]: array([2.5, 5. , 1.2, 1.6])
```

Depending on the size of the arrays, this times 2 to 10x faster than [Stefans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66184840/901925)

I chose this `where` approach because it was the easiest and most compact way of broadcasting `x` with `y`.  It might not be fastest, depending on the 'cost' of the `/` and `*`.